# below program very much confusion about constructor calling very new to java,please explain the concept clearly

Tags: java

```
   class Machine {

     private String name;
     private int code;

     public Machine(){
        this("back",1);
        System.out.println("constructor working!!!!");        
     }

     public Machine(String name){
        this("jick",1);
        System.out.println("Second constructor!!!");
        this.name = name;
     }

     public Machine(String name, int code){
      // this(); compile time error
       //this("back"); //compile time error
           System.out.println("third constructor");
           this.name = name;
            this.code = code;
     }
   }

   public class Constructoroverloading{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      //Machine m1 = new Machine();
      // Machine m2 = new Machine("shruthi");
      // Machine m3 = new Machine("shruthi",20);
    }
 }
```

Here is the program i wrote, i have a doubt that why my third constructor is not able to call first and second constructors. when i tried to call the first or second constructor,compiler is showing that recursive invocation error, i don't really understood the concept clearly and why i am getting that compile time error.

Comment: How can `Machine(String name, int code)` call any of the other two constructors when they them selves call this constructor, it makes no sense

Comment: Try to step through your code if it would compile. You will quickly see why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't think that OP is asking about having *both* lines there, but is saying that both were tried separately: "when i tried to call the first or second constructor...".

Comment: You want the 2nd to call the 3rd and the 3rd to call the 2nd, without end.  Does that make sense to you?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that your code compiles and it looks like

```
 public Machine(){
    this("foo");
    ...
 }

 public Machine(String name){
    this();
    ...
 }
```

Now what will happen if we will invoke one of these constructors? Lets step through this code. We will start with `new Machine("enigma")`:

1. `Machine(String name)` is invoked

   1. and in first instruction it invokes `this();`
   2. so code in `Machine()` is being executed

      1. which in first instruction invokes `this("foo");`
      2. so **again** `Machine(String name)` is invoked

         1. which internally **again** invokes in first instruction `this();`
         2. so **again** `Machine()` is invoked

... (and so on, until stack will overflow). There is no escape from this cycle because first instruction in each constructor is *always* call to *other* constructor from that cycle, which prevents us from adding any code which can solve this problem.
So since compiler sees that there is no proper *stop* point, it prevents you from compiling such code until you correct this mistake.

Comment: @shruthi No problem.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is:

1) You have three different constructors (OK)

2) The first two each call the third (OK)

**...BUT...**

3) The third constructor *CANNOT* call either of the first two ... because then it would effectively be *calling itself*.  This is called [Infinite recursion](https://www.quora.com/What-is-infinite-recursion).

Here is a working example of your code:

```
/*
 * Sample output:
 *   Machine(name, code) constructor: name=back, code=1
 *   default constructor: name=back, code=1
 *   Machine(name, code) constructor: name=jick, code=1
 *   Machine(name) constructor@1: name=shruthi, code=1
 *   Machine(name) constructor@2: name=shruthi, code=1
 *   Machine(name, code) constructor: name=shruthi, code=20
 */
   class Machine {

     private String name = "default";
     private int code = 100;

     public Machine(){
        this("back",1);  // Note: the default constructor calls "Machine(name, code)"
        System.out.println("default constructor: name=" + name + ", code=" + code);        
     }

     public Machine(String name){
        this("jick",1);  // // Note: this constructor ALSO calls "Machine(name, code)"
        System.out.println("Machine(name) constructor@1: name=" + name + ", code=" + code);        
        this.name = name;
        System.out.println("Machine(name) constructor@2: name=" + name + ", code=" + code);        
     }

     public Machine(String name, int code){
        //this(); // error: recursive constructor invocation
        //this("back"); // error: recursive constructor invocation
        //either of these two statements would *call itself infinitely*
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        System.out.println("Machine(name, code) constructor: name=" + name + ", code=" + code);        
     }

   }

   public class Constructoroverloading{

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       Machine m1 = new Machine();
       Machine m2 = new Machine("shruthi");
       Machine m3 = new Machine("shruthi",20);
     }

   }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i understood the whole flow of the program.